# Yesod admin auth with BrowserId and the scaffolded website

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to do a very simple app with Yesod (a blog app) following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SadfV-qbVg8 (I used the scaffolded website)

I want to add a simple authentification to secure the access of the creation of an article.

Following http://www.yesodweb.com/book/authentication-and-authorization, I added:

```
-- Routes not requiring authentication.
isAuthorized (AuthR _) _ = return Authorized
isAuthorized FaviconR _ = return Authorized
isAuthorized RobotsR _ = return Authorized
isAuthorized PublishArticleR _ = isAdmin
-- Default to Authorized for now.
isAuthorized _ _ = return Authorized
```

My new route is PublishArticleR. The isAdmin function is the same as in the book:

```
isAdmin = do
    mu <- maybeAuthId
    return $ case mu of
        Nothing -> AuthenticationRequired
        Just "admin" -> Authorized
        Just _ -> Unauthorized "You must be an admin"
```

And it doesn't compile :(

```
Foundation.hs:76:38:
    No instance for (IsString UserId) arising from a use of ‘isAdmin’
    In the expression: isAdmin
    In an equation for ‘isAuthorized’:
        isAuthorized PublishArticleR _ = isAdmin
    In the instance declaration for ‘Yesod App’
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong…

Thanks,

**EDIT:**

More information about my AuthId, it's defined like this:

```
type AuthId App = UserId
```

My model is:

```
User
    ident Text
    password Text Maybe
    UniqueUser ident
    deriving Typeable
```

And I want to check if the ident property is equal to something (like my email address for example) to authorize to publish new articles.

Comment: In the book page, there is a type synonym for AuthID: type AuthId App = Text, which says that AuthId is equivalent to Text. What's the definition of your UserId?

Comment: I just edit the main post to add more information

Answer (score 1):

`maybeAuthId` will return an `AuthId` object if the user is authenticated. In the example from the yesod book, `AuthId` is only a synonym for `Text`: it's only a user name. `Text` objects (and other types that have `IsString` instances) can be built from string literals, which is why the example code works: Haskell knows how to transform

> "admin"

into a `Text` object.

You're using a more complex type to represent a logged in User, so you either need to provide a IsString instance for User (which will build a user without a password, say):

```
instance IsString User where
   fromString s = User (pack s) ""
```

Or, maybe easier, modify your `isAdmin` function to get the `ident` part of your `User` object, something like:

```
 isAdmin = do
   mu <- maybeAuthId
   return $ case mu of
     Nothing -> AuthenticationRequired
     Just (User ident _) -> case ident of
       "admin" -> Authorized
       _ -> Unauthorized "You must be an admin"
```

EDIT
I misread your definition of AuthId, I thought it was

```
type AuthId App = User
```

In fact, what you have is UserID, which are the IDs of your User objects in your database. So you can do two things: precompute the list of IDs of users that have admin privilege and see if the user id maybeAuthId gives you is one of them, or read the User in the db from the given ID and see if he has the rights...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I now have:
    Foundation.hs:74:38:
        Couldn't match type ‘Key User’ with ‘User’
        Expected type: User
          Actual type: AuthId App
        In the expression: isAdmin
        In an equation for ‘isAuthorized’:
            isAuthorized PublishArticleR _ = isAdmin
        In the instance declaration for ‘Yesod App’

I don't understand what is ident really? The ID from the database? I tried with no success:
        Just ident -> case (get ident) of
            (User "admin" _) -> Authorized

Comment: Ah sorry, there's a mismatch here. Your User is the full object, while maybeAuthId gives back the ID of the user in the db. That's what your error means. So you can do it two ways: retrieve the users from the db that have admin rights, and see if the key given back to you is one of them, or read the user from the id when you get it...

Comment: I don't find how to get the User from the ID in this function (case in case doesn't work as I was expected). Why "Just ident -> case (get ident) of (User "admin" _) -> Authorized" don't work? Thanks

Comment: ident and userId are two different things. The userId is the numeric primary key generated by persistent while ident is the user login name. Maybe you need to change your AuthId to be a Text.